# Android overflow menu positioned above actionbar/toolbar?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I'm trying to get my overflow menu to appear below the top bar in my app. When I was using the Holo theme it did this just fine, but I'm trying to get my app to use material design using the appcompat v7 library.

So my theme now extends from AppCompat:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ucla_blue</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/caldroid_white</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/caldroid_black</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this properly does apply the material design theme to my toolbar in this layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout_root_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.ucla.ieee.app.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
            <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
             space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:name="navigation.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But for some reason, the menu I inflate in onCreateOptionsMenu appears in the wrong place. Apparently I can't post images but basically the overflow menu covers the toolbar instead of appearing just below the toolbar. This started happening when I use "Theme.AppCompat" first in a normal ActionBar and even now with a Toolbar.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            switch (selected) {
                case FRONT_PAGE:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_settings);
                    return false;
                case ANNOUNCEMENTS:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.refresh_settings);
                    return false;
                case MEMBERSHIP:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.edit_member);
                    return false;
                case CALENDAR:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.refresh_settings);
                    return false;
                case POINTS_REWARDS:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_settings);
                    return false;
                case HELP:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_settings);
                    return false;
                default:
                    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.main_settings);
            }
```

Couldn't seem to find anyone experiencing this as well.

Here's an example of one of my menus:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.ucla_ieee.app.MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_refresh"
          app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Per the [Material Design specifications](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) (see the Menus section):

> A menu is a temporary sheet of paper that always overlaps the app bar, rather than behaving as an extension of the app bar.

[image: Menu overlap app bar]

So what you are seeing is the correct Material design for menus.

Comment: Thanks but I have already been doing this in my main activity. It's not that the menu doesn't work, it just looks wrong: http://i.imgur.com/0ybW1A9.png

Comment: Updated my answer given your screenshot: what you are seeing is a Material Design menu.

Comment: Oh darn, guess the apps I have that implemented Material Design gave me the wrong idea. Thanks!!

Comment: @Tania - many haven't moved to the official AppCompat or use an older version (most common among Google apps at this point) but the design specifications and the AppCompat v21 that was released as its code implementation should be considered the source of truth.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'd suggest you give refresh an icon and add `android:showAsAction="ifRoom" app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: hey @Tania you got any solution for this issue ? because i am also finding solution  to place overflow below toolbar. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the answer by @Girish Kumar at [How I can place overflow menu below toolbar instead of overflow menu to overlaps the app bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29445584/how-i-can-place-overflow-menu-below-toolbar-instead-of-overflow-menu-to-overlaps). Shifting the overflow menu to the bottom of app bar is definitely possible.

Answer (score 2):

Some simple steps
Go to android manifest file and search for the activity in which your dropdown menu is present, for mine it's welcome Activity
Now press control and click on the theme name

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

you will move to the styles file where your theme is written
once you go there, you

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now paste these two items there

```
<item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
<item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">5.0dp</item>
```

and you are done...

P.S: Unfortunately I can't share the screenshot here, it seems like SO giving some error on adding images. But you can see on this link
[Image File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByDyNK-YnCLaUkRwNGJlWGVVQ28/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the theme of Activity in manifest than the overflow menu comes below the actionbar

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```