# How to add padding for Menu item in Settings Action Bar from Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I have the following menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
      android:title="@string/refresh_data"
      android:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

How can I add padding on top so that the Button is lower on the menu and doesn't cover the title ?
This menu is from the standard Settings menu in ActionBar.

I've updated it for Lollipop also.

[image]

Comment: But that how [Material design menus look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26639106/1676363). Why do you want to add padding?

Comment: Default padding is 4 * screenDensity. As Ian Lake said, this is how material menues look.

Comment: Is that appcompat? A single menu item should appear vertically centered within the action bar, though there might be an issue with the insets required to display the shadow in appcompat. Regardless, overlapAnchor="true" is the default overflow behavior for Material. You can disable it in your overflow button style, but I wouldn't recommend it.