# ActionBar menu option dialog

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to change the position of the action bar content (Computer,Gamepad..) like in this photo, under the action bar.

[image]

In my application the content start at the top of the screen.

Thanks

Comment: "i want to change the position of the action bar icons like in this photo, under the action bar" -- there is only one "action bar icon" in the photo. It looks like a phone. It is *in* the action bar, not *under* the action bar. Please provide a screenshot that shows "action bar icons like in this photo, under the action bar", or update your description to better match your existing screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use: android:orderInCategory="100"

The higher the number, the further down it is on the list.  Go by 100's

Example:

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_date"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_event"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Date Change"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_search"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26639106/4983722) for your question, so you just cant because of Material Design